# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError 3

Tags: java, c, gcc, java-native-interface

Hi guys i have tried all the solutions like 
java -Djava.library.path=. demo
adding the dll path to PATH
java -Djava.library.path=c:\JNI\demo.dll demo

But still the above error.

Here is my java code..

```
class demo
{
    public native void printline();
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new demo().printline();
    }
}
```

Here is my c code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>

#include "demo.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_demo_printline(JNIEnv *a, jobject b)
{
    printf("Hello wrold!!!");
    return;
}
```

Steps for compiling and running,

1. javac demo.java
2. javah demo
3. gcc -c -I"c:\jdk1.7.0_55\include" -I"c:\jdk1.7.0_55\include\win32" demo.c
4. gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o demo.dll demo.c
5. java -Djava.library.path=c:\JNI\demo.dll demo

Am i going wrong somewhere?

can someone please help me out,.

Comment: Are you sure that its legal to use something like `printf` which caused the big side effects ( writing on stdout buffer ) . Are you sure that JVM doesnt eliminate this kind of actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Run-Time Loading of the dll file within the java code in a static block like:

```
static
{
System.loadLibrary("demo");
}
```

should give you the output.

Moreover make sure that dll file generated is x32 or x64 according to the gcc compiler in use.

Answer (score 0):

looking for "JNI hello world" (or many other terms, possibly), would have given you the answer.

for example:

http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html

- you need to load the library inside your java code
- you need to specify the path to the directory of the library, not to the library itsself, in `java.library.path`